# solve java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=82; regionStart=-1; regionLength=82

Tags: android

I have a project that should copy a text and past it in mobile. but i see this error and after it my app crashes.

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=82; regionStart=-1; regionLength=82
        at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:583)
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1464)
        at com.example.util.Dialogs$4.onClick(Dialogs.java:131)
        at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:157)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This error is for this line of my app:

```
 .setNegativeButton(R.string.text, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    String suggestion = message.substring(
                            message.indexOf(activity.getString(R.string.start)), message.length() - 1
                    );
```

Please help me.

Comment: Did you do any logging to see what the string is that causes this problem?

Comment: How long is the string? What are the indices you are trying to access? Seems like a very easy thing to solve. What have you tried to do to debug the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Your start parameter is -1.  It must be 0 or larger.  indexOf returns -1 if the string isn't found, you need to check for that and either adjust your parameters or not call substring (whichever is appropriate for your usecase).

Comment: my start is here:                                                                                         "your link:
https://wwwnme/hdggd?start=jgjgjc     "                                                                   I could not solve it.